# Google Authenticator app is asking for QR after factory resetting iPhone 11

Tags: ios, google, two-factor-authentication

I had a Google account up and said something about how I was not an administrator of the app, and then I could not do certain things. I'm on an iPhone 11 and I had to factory reset it yesterday. Now, I try to log into my Google Authenticator. It asked for a code or a QR code.

Does anyone know what could possibly be going on with my Google account?

I'm thinking that maybe somebody has made themselves an administrator and has a code set up on my Authenticator app. Could this be true?

Comment: It's not so easy to understand what happened and in which state your phone and Google Authenticator are in now. Can you edit the question to focus on the things you did and the specific problem you have now, without already making assumptions about the cause?

Comment: Having said that: Resetting your iPhone has the same effect on Google Authenticator as transfering to a new phone, so you need to setup Authenticator again.